# Intuition for homeomorphism: are these two spaces homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I realised when attempting the question below, that I have no idea what geometrical operations are 'allowed' in 'deforming' one homeomorphic space into another. The question is:

> Consider the unit disk $D^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $X$ be the
>   compliment of two disjoint open disks in $D^2$.
>
> Let $Y$ be the complement of a single open disk in the 2-dimensional
>   torus, $T^2 = \mathbb{R}^2/ T^2$.
>
> Are X and Y homeomorphic?

So my thoughts were that, **if** we are able to move two arbitrary unit disks in  $D^2$, and reshape them so that they form symmetric cutouts in the disk D^2; **and** we are able to deform the resulting $D^2$ into a square, and double its length along the line in which the cutouts lies, while keeping the cutout disks circular, then what we have formed is isomorphic to $Y$.

However, I lack proper intuition for what is allowed- both in general, and the specific topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or by extension on a torus $T^n$. In particular, can we re-size 'holes' as I have done for X above, to make them the same size? Can we move the 'holes' around arbitrarily provided they remain disjoint? Can we 'square' $D^2$ while keeping the 'holes' circular?

I think, since the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is that induced by the metric $|| \cdot ||_2$, then finding such a homeomorphism would be equivalent to finding a new metric in which the distances between points in $D^2 / \{\text{two open disks}\}$ so that it is like a square, but the metric for the points inside the open discs keeps the distances between the points the same. And then the question would be whether such a thing is continuous.

Comment: One hint would be to think of a torus as the sides of the squares identified and figuring out what removing a disk means(if you have seen connected sums). Also note that the closed disk is homeomorphic to the closed square ( $x \to x/||x||$)

Comment: @SayanChattopadhyay Ah! I did not think of this, but that the closed/open disk and square are homeomorphic, then this applies to the cutouts too! Suppose I squared everything in X (which I think could be thought of as mapping between using a ^||\cdot||_2$ and something that limits to $|| \cdot ||_\infty$ norms) and then I am free to reshape the now-squared cutouts into disks again? Although the continuity of these regions still stumps me. It feels like if I do this, in some cases what a region itself sees to be one shape- a circle say- will be 'seen' to be another shape by the outer region.

Comment: By 'see' I mean if we were to examine things like concavity/convexity, any 'sharp' points, entiraly by seeing how the distance, using a given metric, varies from some fixed points to points 'at the boundary' (defining that carefully!').

Comment: @Meep Intuitively: spaces are homeomorphic if you can stretch, shrink, bend and twist one to get the other. Cutting and glueing isn't allowed! My advice in general: don't think about metric too much.

Comment: The highlighted question is sloppily written, where did you get it from? Depending on the interpretation of the question you can answer it by counting the number of boundary components or by studying separating curves.  In either case, you will need some algebraic topology to answer it (unless you regard, say, Jordan curve theorem as something obvious).